# Why interface methods can't be static in class that implements the interface?

Tags: java, inheritance, static, interface-implementation

Lets suppose I have code like this:

```
public interface JustAnInterface {
    void doSomething();
}

public class JustAnInterfaceImplementation implements JustAnInterface {

    @Override
    public static void doSomething() {

    }
}
```

Why does `static doSomething()` method shows the error "*Method does not override method from its superclass*"?

Comment: Because methods defined in an interface are non-static. Your question is basically circular.

Comment: Static methods in general do not make sense to override. They belong to the class in which they are defined and in that class only, and do not form part of a hierarchy.

Comment: The method signature is different from the interface.

Comment: Because you can't have two methods with same signature where one is static and other non-static. Remember that having non-static one is required by fact that you are implementing interface, so code like `Interface in = new YourImplementation(); in.interfaceMethod();` would be always valid.

Comment: Static methods are "early bound", the implementation of a static method call is known at compile time. Calls to interface methods are "late bound", the implementation is only known at runtime

Comment: I appreciate the super quick accept ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One could say: because @Override and **static** simply do not go together.

Keep in mind: polymorphism only works for non-static methods. **static** means that your method is "attached" to the containing class.

In other words: you know everything about **static** method invocations at compile time. But the process of determining which *overridden* method to invoke happens at runtime. These two concepts do not go together in Java.

Answer (score 2):

All what GhostCat says is correct but the `@Override` annotation is not the direct cause of the compilation error.

Even by removing it, the method is not valid at compile time.

You cannot override or implement a method by adding the `static` modifier in the derived class as overriding/implementing is valid only for instance methods.
Try without the annotation :

```
public class JustAnInterfaceImplementation implements JustAnInterface {

    public static void doSomething() {

    }
}
```

You would have a compilation error more specific than which one with `@Override`

> method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

You should get something like :

> overriding method is static

Answer (score 1):

The static and non-static methods have different signatures, and not simply because of the `static`.

The non-static method is secretly taking an extra parameter - the value of `this`.

If you're familiar with python, you can see this explicitly:

```
class SomeClass(object):
  def doSomething(self):
    pass // whatever method body
```

Here, the `self` parameter is just a regular parameter: you can invoke the method and pass this parameter yourself.

In Java, it's sort of the same. When you invoke the `doSomething` method, you implicitly pass one parameter to it, and that becomes `this`.

However, the static method takes *zero* parameters. So actually, they aren't override-equivalent, and hence you aren't overriding the method correctly.

The JVM would have to somehow determine that the parameter should be discarded. The language could have been written to allow this, but the designers took the easier route of just disallowing it (because there's no good reason to use it anyway).